# Replace instance of process in place?

Tags: shell-script, process, process-management

I suspect this is not doable just because of the security implications, but here's what I'd like to do.

Basically we run a bash shell-script on our CentOS server that calls `Program-A` (in our case JMeter, but that is arbitrary) which runs and dumps data into a log file. After that process finishes the shell-script starts up `Program-B` to analyze the log.

What I would like to do is stop the instance of `Program-A1` and replace it with another instance of `Program-A2`, or some how swap them in place so I can safely end `Program-A1` without starting up `Program-B` prematurely.

Why would I want to do this? The main reason is that `Program-A` loads some configuration files at its startup and if we make changes to those config files we have to restart the program for them to take effect, which I'd like to avoid.

I understand this is most likely not possible, but if it is I would greatly appreciate the information.

EDIT: I suppose I wasn't clear enough. Basically my shellscript looks like this:

```
./Program-A
./Program-B
```

When `Program-A` finishes dumping to our log, `Program-B` picks up the log and parses it. The problem I'm having is sometimes `Program-A`'s settings are not set correctly or something is wrong with the environment when it starts which means that we'll need to run the whole thing again. We'd like to avoid that  by just replacing our first instance of `Program-A` (calling it `Program-A1`) with a new instance of `Program-A` (we'll call this `Program-A2`). Does this make more sense to everyone?

The main reason we would like to do this is because `Program-A` and `Program-B`  are actually a single part of a GIANT shell script that takes hours to run. Rather than restart the whole process for one individual part, we'd like to restart the single troubled program.

Comment: At the start of `Program-A`, touch a file `IN_PROGRESS`, and upon finish mv `IN_PROGRESS` to `FINISHED`. In the beginning of `Program-B` check if `IN_PROGRESS` exists or not. If it is, back off the current running.

Comment: The problem is not that I need to prevent `Program-B` from starting, the problem is I need to restart `Program-A` in place because it is part of a long series of commands that have to be run in order. Just quitting the script would cost irrecoverable hours of processing time. Thanks though, I'll keep that trick under my hat

Comment: You can still utilize this trick. For example, let `Program-B` run every minutes using crontab, but check if any `Program-A` has finished before running the actual code.

Comment: In this instance I don't think this will work. The reason being in my case this shell script has many programs it runs (both before and after) and can take several hours. So while this could work in many cases, in this instance it's not really an elegant solution for me. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are trying to replace a RUNNING process from OUTSIDE the process. That's some radical stuff.

When I first looked at the question, it seemed that you are looking exactly for `exec`. But `exec` is called by the program itself. So unless you have coded the process so that you can force it to just exec another process, you can't do that while it is running.

You could potentially create a signal trap in your Program-A to `exec` a program with predefined name (which you can then set to be whatever you want) and then use `kill` on this process to force it to `exec`. From the outside, it will look like the process kept running - it does, it just becomes someone else. However, if you haven't done that and you want to do this on a running process, I don't think you can do anything.

However, if the outer shell is running, but it hasn't started the critical process yet, you can just replace the file of the problematic process.

Answer (score 4):

The only way you can do this is to send a STOP signal to Program-A, then use gdb (Gnu debugger) to replace the suspended code with the code from Program-A1. The complexity of this is likely beyond what you're willing to invest (see http://mohit.io/blog/debugging-modifying-code-at-runtime/), so I suggest an alternative:

edit your bash script to "trap" the exit from Program-A. then prompt for manual intervention, at that point you must explicity respond "y" it is safe to proceed with Program-B. One way to do this is to put a while loop around Program -A, capture the exit code, if it is not a successful exit, then prompt for user intervention, keep looping until a valid exit is encountered. Then proceed onto Program-B.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can just suspend Program-A and start Program-A1, and when Program-A1 finishes, kill Program-A and resume it (at which point it will handle the SIGTERM, die, and your script will carry on with Program-B):

```
killall -s STOP Program-A
Program-A1
killall Program-A
killall -s CONT Program-A
```

If you want `Program-A1` to inherit the environment from `Program-A`, and if on Linux (and assuming all of the environment strings of `Program-A` contain at least a `=` character as they usually do), you can do:

```
xargs -0 --arg-file="/proc/$(pidof Program-A
  )/environ" sh -c 'exec env -i "$@" Program-A1' sh >> file.log
```

Comment: That is actually a good idea. That might be what I'm looking for, our work schedule won't permit me from experimenting with this today but I'll give this a try

Comment: This won't work. The bash script is waiting for an EXIT signal from the original pid (program-A). This will get triggered upon "killall Program-A", which will trigger Program-B to start while Program-A1 is still going.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez, `killall Program-A` is run after `Program-A1` has finished. And Program-A won't handle SIGTERM until it's resumed.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, good catch. I quickly skimmed the answer and didn't pay attention to the ordering. .... So this should work, unless Program-A holds a write lock on the log file which would prevent Program-A1 from writing to it. ... I think the better solution is the answer I give below.

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest things to do in a shell script is to run programs sequentially. You can do something like this:

```
if Program-A
then
    Program-B
else
    # handle problems
    if Program-A
    then
        Program-B
    else
        # Program-A failed twice in a row, get help.
    fi
fi
```

That kind of construct will prevent Program-B from running prematurely.

If you can change the source code to Program-A, you can take advantage of the `execve()` system call, which causes the kernel to overlay the program calliing `execve()` with the code and data from another executable file. A lot of things carry through the `execve()` call like open file descriptors, Process ID, but some things don't. You'll have to read up to see what modifications to make.

If I read between the lines of what you write, you may want to do a fork/other work/exec combination of system calls: the `fork()` would give you two processes, one of which could start Program-B, while the other goes on to `execve()` Program-A1. Or something.  You should clarify what you want.

Further out in left field, it's possible to do a "[userland exec](http://www.stratigery.com/userlandexec.html)". If all you want to do is "swap" one program for another, you can do that without an `execve()` system call, although the `execve()` is probably more efficient, and certainly less error prone.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I wasn't clear enough. The shell script is calling Program-A and then Program-B sequentially, I just want to be able to restart Program-A without it moving on to Program-B. Is that more sensical?

Comment: @SonofLysander - see changed program fragment above.

Answer (score 0):

So below you'll find this really long and probably error prone mockup of how I think such a thing might work. It inserts an `exec`ing function **ab_start** between **program_a** and **program_b** to ensure their respective **lock** files are cleaned up between calls to either function and an overlapping **switch.lock** is deployed for each call to **ab_start**. So:

- **program_a** will not begin function until both its `trap` is set and it successfully removes **switch.lock**. Then it does whatever until **program_b.lock** shows up, all the while piping its log through `sed`.
- **`sed`** monitors **program_a**'s log output for the `regex` **signal_output** at which time it opens **program_b.lock** and writes the captured line to it.

  - Meanwhile though, `sed` is happy to also pump all log data streamed through it into **program_a.log**, like a smart `tee`.
- **program_a** wraps up its last loop and tragically `kill`s itself.
- but **program_a** has trapped the *USR1* signal already, so it opens the previously unevaluated **`/dev/fd/4 <<SUSPEND`** file appended to its input and executes it. It then:

  - **`touch`es switch.lock**
  - **`&`** backgrounds a call to **ab_start** with instructions to start **program_b**
  - **`while`** waits for both **program_b.lock** and **switch.lock** to magically disappear at which time it...
  - **`touch`es switch.lock**
  - calls **ab_start** with instructions to **`exec`** right back into itself.
- *meanwhile...*
- **ab_start** saves its **`exec`** target parameter and shifts it away, then

  - refuses to do anything but `sleep` or `rm` until both **`{a_b}.lock`s** have disappeared
  - frustratedly **`touch`es `{a_b}.lock`**
  - **`exec`s** into its target
- *last*...
- - **program_b** sets itself a **`trap`** then
  - refuses to do anything but `sleep` or `rm` until **`switch.lock`** is gone.
  - does whatever it does for however long it takes and when through
  - **`kill`s** itself
  - but finds temporary reprieve in its own **`DIE`** appended `here-document`
  - until it successfully removes **`program_b.lock`**
  - and then it really dies
- **BUT**
- **program_a** then wakes up and **`exec`s** itself as explained above.

  HASHBANG

  ```
  ab_start() { a_b="$1" ; shift
          while [ -e /locks/program_a.lock ] ||\
                [ -e /locks/program_b.lock ] ; do {
                rm /locks/program_[ab].lock
                sleep 1
         } ; done
         touch /locks/"${a_b}.lock"
         exec "$0" "${a_b}" "$@"
  } 

  program_a() { trap '. /dev/fd/4' USR1 ; 
      while [ -e /locks/switch.lock ] ; do {
          rm /locks/switch.lock ; sleep 1
      } ; done
      until [ -e /locks/program_b.lock ] ; do {
          stuff...
          it...
          does...
      } ; done |\
              sed 's/signal_output/w /locks/program_b.lock'\
                  >> /logs/program_a.log
      kill -USR1 $$
  } 4<<-\SUSPEND
      touch /locks/switch.lock
      ab_start program_b "$@" &
      while [ -e /locks/switch.lock ] ||\
          [ -e /locks/program_b.lock ] ; do
          sleep 10 
      done
      touch /locks/switch.lock 
      ab_start program_a "$@"
  #   END
      SUSPEND

  program_b() { trap '. /dev/fd/5' INT QUIT TERM EXIT
      while [ -e /locks/switch.lock ] ; do {
          rm /locks/switch.lock ; sleep 1
      } ; done
      while $work ; do { 
          stuff ...
          it ...
          does ...
      } ; done
  } 5<<-\DIE
      while [ -e /locks/program_b.lock ] ; do {
          rm /locks/program_b.lock ; sleep 1
      } ; done
  exec 5<&0 <&-
  #   NOW
      DIE
  ```

  "$@"

I'll apologize now for whatever egregious errors I may have made above, but I believe this kind of thing could work so... take it as you will. No warranty though.

Definitely at least `sed` I think is a good idea here.